# Problem with curl and scripting for OpenStack

Tags: bash, sh, openstack

I'm presently doing a shell script to create some networks / VMs on Openstack.  Here, I'm first getting the token and then I'm trying to list all images. However, there seems to be some kind of problem with an environment variable

```
echo "GETTING TOKEN"
res=$( curl -sD - -o /dev/null \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '
...
}' \
http://$1/identity/v3/auth/tokens)

token=$(echo "$res" | awk '/X-Subject-Token: /{print $NF}')

export OS_TOKEN="$token"

echo $OS_TOKEN

echo  "X-Auth-Token: $OS_TOKEN"

curl -s \
--header "X-Auth-Token: $OS_TOKEN" \
 http://$1/image/v2/images
```

this is the output that i'm getting :

```
devstack@MFZhani:~$ ./script.sh localhost
GETTING TOKEN
THE TOKEN
X-Auth-Token: THE SAME TOKEN
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

The thing is, when I hardcode the token, it works. Also, I know it's not caused by a bad character in the variable because I'm doing other commands with the exact same token for creating networks and it works just fine (the difference here is that i'm doing a GET instead of a POST).

Comment: try with `set -x`

Comment: like this : curl -s set -x\
--header "X-Auth-Token: $OS_TOKEN" \
 http://$1/image/v2/images ??

Comment: add `set -x` to the beginning of the script, on the first line. Run. Observe the output. The lines starting `+` are commands that are executing. Search google on how to debug bash scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it with the `set -x` suggested by Kamil Cuk. There was a \r that I was not able to see otherwise. Deleted it and it worked. Thanks.